# Play2 Scala Json custom Format Combinator

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I've the following model:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int, job: Option[String])

object PersonJsonFormats {
    implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Person]
}
```

Converting a `Person` object into Json (e.g. with `Json.toJson(person)`) produces the following Json object.

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 10,
    "job": "gardener"
}
```

What should I change in order to produce an object like the following instead?

```
[
    {
        "name": "name",
        "value" : "John"
    },
    {
        "name": "age",
        "value": 10
    },
    {
        "name": "job",
        "value": "gardener"
    }
]
```

I know I could write custom `Reads` and `Writes` but I want to write something I can apply to every `case class`

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to write custom Reads and Writes and want something that you can apply to every `case class`, you probably should use macros to to this.

That's how the [original](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaJsonInception) automatic implicit converters are build.

Places to look:

- [Json.scala](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/97ceddf54cfc9eb6d2b8b38e3ad7d84eddc83b71/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/Json.scala#L204)
- [JsMacroImpl.scala](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/97ceddf54cfc9eb6d2b8b38e3ad7d84eddc83b71/framework/src/play-json/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsMacroImpl.scala#L42)

Comment: I had a quick look at those docs. I think this is a little bit beyond my Scala knowledge :)